# smoothness of hopf fibration projection with respect to standard differentiable structure on unit sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

We know that steographic projection defines a differentiable structure on $S^n$ by sending points on $S^n$ to hyperplane $\{x^{n+1}\}=0$. In fact, stereographic projection $\sigma_P: S^n- P\to R^n $ is a map which sends a point $X\in S^n- P$ to the unique point where PX intersect $R^n$, where P is N or S respectively.

Now , it can be calculated that $\sigma_N(x^1,x^2,...,x^{n+1})= \frac{1}{1-x^{n+1}}(x^1,x^2,...,x^n)$ and $\sigma_S(x^1,x^2,...,x^{n+1})= \frac{1}{1+x^{n+1}}(x^1,x^2,...,x^n)$ . Also , it is easy to show that $\{S^n- N,\sigma_N\}$,$\{S^n- S,\sigma_S\}$ defines a differentiable structure on $S^n$.

I was further asked to compute the coordinate representation for each of these maps below in stereographic coordinates and use this to show each map is smooth.

a) antipodal map $ a:S^n \to S^n $ that sends x to -x.

b) Hopf fibration projection $\pi:S^3\to S^2 $,defined by $\pi(z_1,z_2)=(2Re(z_1z_2),2Im(z_1\bar{z_2}),|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2)$ ,where $S^3$ is the unit sphere, $\{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1\}$,in $C^2$.

I have no idea how to do this part . Can anyone help me with this part?

Comment: I think your formulas need a bit of work.  More specifically, for the Hopf fibration, what do you mean by $Re(z_1,z_2)$?  What do you mean by $|z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2 = 1$ as part of a function definition?

Comment: I've corrected typo

Comment: I think $Im$ still needs some work.  Further, the point $p=\left(1/2 + 1/2i, \, 1/2+1/2 i\right)$ is in $S^3$, but even with $Im$ fixed, you get $\pi(p) = (0, 0, 0)\notin S^2$.  I think that the $z_2$ in $Re$ needs to have a complex conjugate.  (I'll type up an answer shortly)

Comment: again I corrected typo

Answer (score 3):

I'll sketch the Hopf fibration case, leaving you the antipodal map case.

The point of charts is that, locally, they give a way of thinking about a map $f:M\rightarrow N$ between two manifolds as a map between Euclidean spaces.  More specifically, suppose $M$ is $m$-dimensional and $N$ is $n$-dimensional.  Let $p\in M$ and choose a chart $(U,\varphi)$ around $p$ and a chart $(V,\rho)$ around $f(p)$.  In other words, $\varphi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a homeomorphism onto an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and likewise for $\rho:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then the composition $\rho \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ makes sense and actually defines a map from an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  In this setting, we know how to make sense of the statement $\rho \circ f\circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth (or $C^1$, differentiable, etc) and we *define* the analytic properties of $f$ to be those of $\rho \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$.

Thus, in order to prove that $f:M\rightarrow N$ is $C^\infty$, we really have to show that for every point $p\in M$, $\rho \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth.

Now, to your particular example, we must pick a point $p$ in $S^3$, pick charts around both $p$ and $\pi(p)$, and then compute the corresponding map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

First, using the map from wikipedia, we have $$\pi(z_1, z_2) = \left(2\Re(z_1 \overline{z_2}),\, 2\Im(z_1\overline{z_2}),\, |z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2 \right).$$

First note that $\pi(z_1,z_2)$ really is an element of $S^2$ with this definition.  This follows because \begin{align} |\pi(z_1,z_2)| &= 4\Re(z_1\overline{z_2})^2 + 4\Im(z_1\overline{z_2})^2 + \left(|z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2\right)^2\\ &= 4|z_1\overline{z_2}|^2 + |z_1|^4 -2|z_1|^2|z_2|^2 + |z_2|^4\\ &= |z_1|^4 + 2|z_1|^2|z_2|^2 + |z_2|^4\\ &= (|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2)^2 \\ &= 1.\end{align}

Now, to check smoothness, instead of using complex number "coordinates" on $S^3$, I'm going to use regular good old fashioned $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ where $z_1 = x_1 + i x_2$ and $z_2 = x_3 + i x_4$ and, of course, $\sum x_i^2 = 1$.

With these "coordinates", $\pi$ looks like $$\pi(x_1,x_2,x_3, x_4) = (2x_1x_3 +2x_2x_4, \,2x_2 x_3 - 2x_1 x_4,\, x_1^2 + x_2^2 - x_3^3 - x_4^2).$$

Now, choose any point $p = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in S^3$ where we'll assume that $p$ is not the north pole of $S^3$, meaning, say, $x_4\neq 1$.  We will also assume that $\pi(p)$ is not the north pole of $S^2$.  With these assumptions, we can use $\varphi = \sigma^3_N$ on $S^3$ and $\rho = \sigma^2_N$ on $S^2$.  (The superscripts on the $\sigma$s refer to which sphere they're defined on.)

Then (according to wikipedia) $$\varphi^{-1}(x_1, x_2, x_3) = \frac{1}{1+x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}(2x_1,\, 2x_2,\, 2x_3,\, x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 - 1).$$

Now, I'll leave it to you to actually compute $\rho \circ \pi \circ \varphi^{-1}$.  This ends up being a map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a rational function in each coordinate.  I will also leave it to you to show that, perhaps after shrinking the chart around $p$, the denominator of each rational function is always nonzero, so that $\rho \circ \pi circ \varphi^{-1}$ is actually smooth.  Then, by definition, $\pi$ is smooth at the point $p$.

To finish up this example, one should remove the assumptions that both $p$ and $f(p)$ are not their respective north poles.  To remove these assumptions, use the other charts $\sigma_S^3$ and $\sigma_S^2$.

Comment: I calculate the rational function as $\frac{1}{{(1+{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2)}^2+{({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2-1)}^2-4{x_1}^2-4{x_2}^2+4{x_3}^2}(8x_1x_3+4x_2({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2-1),8x_2x_3-4x_1({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2-1) )$ 

So the denominator is$ 2+2{x_1}^4+2{x_2}^4+2{x_3}^4+4{x_2}^2{x_1}^2+4{x_3}^2{x_1}^2+4{x_3}^2{x_2}^2-4{x_1}^2-4{x_2}^2+4{x_3}^2$

Comment: However , I cant show the denorminator is nonzero at every point in $R^3$ even after a few attempts

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily nonzero at every point in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  But we picked a $p$ different from the north pole of $S^3$ where $\pi(p)$ is different from the north pole of $S^2$.  Writing $p = (z_1,z_2)$, this means that $z_1\neq 1$ and $|z_1|\neq 1$.  Translating this into $x$ stuff, you should be able to argue that on some smaller neighborhood around $\varphi(p)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the denominator in the rational function is nonzero.  (In fact, by continuity of polynomials, it's enough to show that the denominator evaluated at $\varphi(p)$ is nonzero.)

Comment: In fact, by assumption, we have that the third coordinate of $(\pi \circ \varphi^{-1})(\varphi(p))$ is not $1$ (since $\pi(p)$ is not the north pole!).  That's good enough to get $\rho\circ\pi \circ \varphi$ to be smooth at $p$.